# Merging two array of objects only when array element contains error

Tags: javascript

So I have two arrays with objects. And also an array indicating where the replacement should take place(It spots if object contains error)

```
         const oldData = [
    {
        "index": "01",
        "skuId": "Sarbb-033",
        "name": "Sasko Black",
        "barcode": "843331510012",
        "description": "Nice black bread",
        "brand": "ERROR: No brand matching: Sasko",
        "productLine": "ERROR: No product line matching: line",
        "inputType": "Weight",
        "uom": "ERROR: Invalid UoM type, valid values are: kg,g,mg,kl,l,ml,m,cm,mm",
        "value": "700",
        "capacity": "1",
        "image": ""
    },
    {
        "index": "02",
        "skuId": "ERROR: Empty sku_id is not allowed",
        "name": "Sasko Black1",
        "barcode": "ERROR: Empty barcode is not allowed",
        "description": "Nice black bread",
        "brand": "ERROR: No brand matching: Future Life",
        "productLine": "ERROR: No product line matching: line",
        "inputType": "Weight",
        "uom": "kg",
        "value": "701",
        "capacity": "2",
        "image": ""
    },
    {
        "index": "03",
        "skuId": "Sarbb-099",
        "name": "Sasko Black100",
        "barcode": "843332555614",
        "description": "Nice black bread",
        "brand": "fwfwf",
        "productLine": "naam",
        "inputType": "weight",
        "uom": "g",
        "value": "702",
        "capacity": "3",
        "image": ""
    },
    {
        "index": "04",
        "skuId": "Sarbb-100",
        "name": "Sasko Black101",
        "barcode": "ERROR: Empty barcode is not allowed",
        "description": "ERROR: Invalid description: [] it should not be blank.",
        "brand": "fwfwf",
        "productLine": "fwfwf",
        "inputType": "Weight",
        "uom": "g",
        "value": "703",
        "capacity": "4",
        "image": ""
    },
    {
        "index": "05",
        "skuId": "Sarbb-101",
        "name": "Sasko Black102",
        "barcode": "843332555616",
        "description": "Nice black bread",
        "brand": "fwfwf",
        "productLine": "naam",
        "inputType": "weight",
        "uom": "g",
        "value": "704",
        "capacity": "5",
        "image": ""
    }
]


    const newData = [
    {
        "index": "01",
        "skuId": "Sarbb-033",
        "name": "Sasko Black",
        "barcode": "843331510012",
        "description": "Nice black bread",
        "brand": "fwfwf",
        "productLine": "fwfwf",
        "inputType": "Weight",
        "uom": "g",
        "value": "700",
        "capacity": "1",
        "image": ""
    },
    {
        "index": "02",
        "skuId": "sarb",
        "name": "Sasko Black1",
        "barcode": "124125125",
        "description": "Nice black bread",
        "brand": "fwfwf",
        "productLine": "fwfwf",
        "inputType": "Weight",
        "uom": "kg",
        "value": "701",
        "capacity": "2",
        "image": ""
    },
    {
        "index": "03",
        "skuId": "Sarbb-100",
        "name": "Sasko Black101",
        "barcode": "214214214",
        "description": "Desc",
        "brand": "fwfwf",
        "productLine": "fwfwf",
        "inputType": "Weight",
        "uom": "g",
        "value": "703",
        "capacity": "4",
        "image": ""
    }
]

    const errorRows = [0,1,3]


      const myTerribleAttempt = oldTableData.map((oldData, rowIndex) => {
  return errorRows.map(index => {
    if(rowIndex === index){
     newTableData.map(newData => {
oldData = newData
     })
    }
  })
 })
```

I have tried multiple maps and just can't seem to get the right result. The new data objects should replace old data objects at the object containing the error. Please give me some assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've overcomplicated this - just check if the index is contained in the error array and choose old or new data.

```
const result =  oldData.map( (item, idx) => errorRows.includes(idx) 
                   ? newData[errorRows.findIndex(x => x == idx)] 
                   : item);
```

live example:

```js
const oldData = [{
    "index": "01",
    "skuId": "Sarbb-033",
    "name": "Sasko Black",
    "barcode": "843331510012",
    "description": "Nice black bread",
    "brand": "ERROR: No brand matching: Sasko",
    "productLine": "ERROR: No product line matching: line",
    "inputType": "Weight",
    "uom": "ERROR: Invalid UoM type, valid values are: kg,g,mg,kl,l,ml,m,cm,mm",
    "value": "700",
    "capacity": "1",
    "image": ""
  },
  {
    "index": "02",
    "skuId": "ERROR: Empty sku_id is not allowed",
    "name": "Sasko Black1",
    "barcode": "ERROR: Empty barcode is not allowed",
    "description": "Nice black bread",
    "brand": "ERROR: No brand matching: Future Life",
    "productLine": "ERROR: No product line matching: line",
    "inputType": "Weight",
    "uom": "kg",
    "value": "701",
    "capacity": "2",
    "image": ""
  },
  {
    "index": "03",
    "skuId": "Sarbb-099",
    "name": "Sasko Black100",
    "barcode": "843332555614",
    "description": "Nice black bread",
    "brand": "fwfwf",
    "productLine": "naam",
    "inputType": "weight",
    "uom": "g",
    "value": "702",
    "capacity": "3",
    "image": ""
  },
  {
    "index": "04",
    "skuId": "Sarbb-100",
    "name": "Sasko Black101",
    "barcode": "ERROR: Empty barcode is not allowed",
    "description": "ERROR: Invalid description: [] it should not be blank.",
    "brand": "fwfwf",
    "productLine": "fwfwf",
    "inputType": "Weight",
    "uom": "g",
    "value": "703",
    "capacity": "4",
    "image": ""
  },
  {
    "index": "05",
    "skuId": "Sarbb-101",
    "name": "Sasko Black102",
    "barcode": "843332555616",
    "description": "Nice black bread",
    "brand": "fwfwf",
    "productLine": "naam",
    "inputType": "weight",
    "uom": "g",
    "value": "704",
    "capacity": "5",
    "image": ""
  }
]


const newData = [{
    "index": "01",
    "skuId": "Sarbb-033",
    "name": "Sasko Black",
    "barcode": "843331510012",
    "description": "Nice black bread",
    "brand": "fwfwf",
    "productLine": "fwfwf",
    "inputType": "Weight",
    "uom": "g",
    "value": "700",
    "capacity": "1",
    "image": ""
  },
  {
    "index": "02",
    "skuId": "sarb",
    "name": "Sasko Black1",
    "barcode": "124125125",
    "description": "Nice black bread",
    "brand": "fwfwf",
    "productLine": "fwfwf",
    "inputType": "Weight",
    "uom": "kg",
    "value": "701",
    "capacity": "2",
    "image": ""
  },
  {
    "index": "03",
    "skuId": "Sarbb-100",
    "name": "Sasko Black101",
    "barcode": "214214214",
    "description": "Desc",
    "brand": "fwfwf",
    "productLine": "fwfwf",
    "inputType": "Weight",
    "uom": "g",
    "value": "703",
    "capacity": "4",
    "image": ""
  }
]

const errorRows = [0, 1, 3];

const result = oldData.map((item, idx) => errorRows.includes(idx) ? newData[idx] : item);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I realised this is not always going to work. Lets say the error is at index 4. NewData only has 3 indexes so will return an undefined object

Comment: @Deeve so what do you want to do in that case? Keep the bad data?

Comment: No not at all. I forgot to mention that the data in newData is in the order of the fixes that were made so the indexes don't match the index in old data. So newData at index three should be the third error fix on oldData(even if the third item in oldData that has an error is at index 5)

Comment: @Deeve see the update - I think that should now do what you expect

Comment: Our ux team decided to make the indexes match so that made this whole situation easier. Your new solution worked perfectly in any case.Hopefully this can help someone.  I appreciate your help. Thank you!!